# Aptana Simple Inline Conditionals for PHP

Tags: php, aptana

I typically use Eclipse as main PHP and JS editor.  While the JS Formatting piece does what I want, the PHP Formatting seems completely lacking.  Thus, I'd prefer to use Aptana Studio.  However, PHP Formatting does at least one annoyance that I'd like to change.  The Formatter for Aptana has so many options already, it's surprising that this is not an option.

I prefer for simple inline conditionals to be all on one line, like this:

```
if ($test == FALSE) return FALSE;
```

However, Aptana PHP formats like this:

```
if ($test == FALSE)
    return FALSE;
```

This gets really annoying when you test anything more than 1 at a time:

```
if ($test1 == FALSE) return FALSE;
if ($test2 == 14) return FALSE;
if ($test3 == "") return FALSE;
```

becomes:

```
if ($test1 == FALSE) 
    return FALSE;
if ($test2 == 14) 
    return FALSE;
if ($test3 == "") 
    return FALSE;
```

I wondered if there was a manual way to force that type of formatting.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to force it at the moment. The `if` body is wrapped as a block and forced to the second line.

What you'll need to do is to ask for an improvement here: http://aptana.com/r/apbugs